# Escape double quotes in URL for execution with curl command

Tags: perl, curl

I have the following URL to be executed with `curl`

```
my $workItemCommentorURL = "://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId="$id"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title"
```

I get the error as:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at ./clone.pl line 90, near ""://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId="$id"
    (Missing operator before $id?)
String found where operator expected at ./clone.pl line 90, near "$id"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title""
```

Tried to escape double quotes with following options:

```
"://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId=\"&id\"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title"
"https://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:\"userId=" .$id. "\"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title"
```

With this able to get the result but still getting the warning message as:

```
sh: oslc_cm.properties=dc:title: command not found
```

How should I escape the quotes in URL to get the result without warning `sh: oslc_cm.properties=dc:title: command not found`

My code is:

```
my $workItemCommentorURL = "https://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId=\"$id\"&oslc_cm.
my $result = qx(curl -s -D - -k  -b ~/.jazzcookies -o commentor.json -H \"Accept: application/x-oslc-cm-changerequest+json\" $workItemCommentorURL);
```

Answer (score 4):

The message you get from `sh` is caused by the `&` in the url. The url needs to be escaped/quoted for the shell. Otherwise the shell interprets the `&` as a special character.

Try this (notice the single quotes):

```
my $result = qx(curl -s -D - -k  -b ~/.jazzcookies -o commentor.json -H 'Accept: application/x-oslc-cm-changerequest+json' '$workItemCommentorURL');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to interpolate variables.  Use single quotes:

```
my $workItemCommentorURL = '://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId="$id"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title';
```

If you do want interpolation, then use the alternative form [`qq{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html):

```
my $workItemCommentorURL = qq{://xyz.com/jazz/oslc/users.json?oslc_cm.query=rtc_cm:userId="$id"&oslc_cm.properties=dc:title};
```